# Recuperar String entre caracteres

Tags: java, string

Olá, estou desenvolvendo um programa que usa a linha de comando do java
se o usuário digitar: send -all < mensagem a ser enviada > ele envia a mensagem para todos
caso seja send -by < usuario > < mensagem a ser enviada > ele envia para um usuário especifico.
Esses comandos chegam em String, minha dúvida é como recuperar essa informação e chamar o método especifico, tentei com split, mas não consegui. As mensagem ficam entre < >.

Comment: Quando você diz que ele usa a linha de comando, você quer dizer a linha de comando mesmo (tipo: `java MinhaClasse send -all < mensagem a ser enviada >`) ou ele lê esse comando da entrada padrão (tipo: `System.in`)? Como está seu código até o momento?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considerando a chamada:

```
java MeuPrograma -by<usuario> -<mensagem>
```

Você pode simplesmente utilizar os parâmetros enviados para o método `main`:

```
public class ClasseQuePossuiMetodoPrincipal {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        System.out.println(args[0]); // Vai exibir -by<usuario>
        System.out.println(args[1]); // Vai exibir -<mensagem>
    }
}
```

Ambos são entregues para a sua aplicação como uma `String`, inclusive contendo os caracteres especiais que enviou. Para removê-los e ter uma *string* mais amigável, pode fazer assim:

```
public class ClasseQuePossuiMetodoPrincipal {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        System.out.println(clear(args[0])); // Vai exibir byusuario (pode usar um String#substring para remover o 'by' no início)
        System.out.println(clear(args[1])); // Vai exibir mensagem
    }

    private static String clear(String str){
        return str.replaceAll("[^\\dA-Za-z ]", "");
    }
}
```

#### Sugestão de implementação

Uma forma melhor de se fazer é chamando sua aplicação Java das formas seguintes:

Quando quiser enviar a todos: `java MeuPrograma "Mensagem que será enviada a todos."`
E quando quiser enviar a um usuário específico: `java MeuPrograma "Olá, como vai?" "foo"`

Deste modo, você pode verificar a quantidade de argumentos enviados. Se enviado um único parâmetro, consideramos então que a mensagem deve ser entregue a todos. Do contrário, se forem enviados dois argumentos significa que a mensagem deve ser enviada a um usuário específico.

Então sua classe poderia ficar assim:

```
public class ClasseQuePossuiMetodoPrincipal {
    public static void main(String... args) {
         //Faz aqui algum tratamento caso args.lenght seja zero.
         //E verifica se args.lenght é igual a 2.

        if(args.lenght == 1)
            send(args[0]); // Todos
        else 
            send(args[0], args[1]); // Envia para um usuário
    }

    private static void send(String message){
        // Envia para todos...
    }

    private static void send(String message, String who){
        // Envia para 'who'...
    }
}
```

Aproveitando a mesma ideia, se quiser permitir que o usuário utilize a aplicação enviando o conteúdo da mensagem seguida de uma lista de usuário para o qual a mensagem deve ser enviada, por exemplo:

```
java MeuPrograma "Mensagem para os usuários a seguir..." "joao" "mario" "carlos"
```

Sua classe poderia ser implementada assim:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ClasseQuePossuiMetodoPrincipal {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        //Faz aqui algum tratamento para verificar se args.lenght é igual ou maior que 1.
        String mensagem = args[0];

        if(args.length == 1)
            send(mensagem);

        else {
            ArrayList<String> usuarios = new ArrayList<>();

            // Começando em 1 pois 0 é a mensagem, já armazenada na variável 'mensagem'
            for(int i = 1; i < args.length; i++)
                usuarios.add(args[i]);
            send(mensagem, usuarios);
        }
    }

    private static void send(String message){
        // Envia para todos
    }

    private static void send(String message, ArrayList<String> sendTo){
        // Envia para todos os usuários na lista 'sendTo'
    }
}
```

Comment: Valeu cara, era isso mesmo :)